# Strong sub-differentiability of an equivalent strictly convex norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

First, we define the notion of strong sub-differentiability(SSD) of a norm on a Banach space $X$. The norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ of $X$ is said to be SSD if the one-sided limit $$\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{\Vert x+th\Vert - \Vert x \Vert}{t} $$ exists uniformly for $h \in S_X,$ and $x \in S_X=\{x \in X:\Vert x \Vert=1\}$. I have seen this result: "The norm of $\ell_1$ is SSD at every norm one norm attaining functional on $c_0$". A functional $f \in X^*$ attains its norm on $B_X$ if there exists $x_0 \in B_X$ such that
$$
\langle f, x_0 \rangle =\sup \{ \langle f, y \rangle : y \in B_X \}.
$$ Here, the set of all functionals in $X^∗$ that attain their norm is called the norm-attaining set, denoted by $NA((X, \Vert \cdot \Vert))$.
Now, let us consider the mapping $T:\ell_1(\Gamma) \to \ell_2(\Gamma)$ and define a strictly convex dual norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ on $\ell_1(\Gamma)$ by  $$ \Vert x \Vert=\Vert x \Vert_1+\Vert Tx \Vert_2,$$ for $x \in \ell_1(\Gamma)$. Here $\Gamma$ is an infinite index set. Now, if we consider $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$, does this norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is SSD at $f \in NA(c_0(\mathbb{N}))$. Kindly help me with my confusion. Thank you.

For reference, This new norm has been defined in [Book-Renormings in Banach spaces-pp-155 by Antonio J. Guirao, V. Zizler, and V. Montesinos].

Comment: (i) What is $\Gamma$? (ii) The notation $NA(X)$ seems to be not good, since it does not reflect the dependence on $x$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I have made edits to my question.

Comment: "if we consider $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$" -- What do you mean by that? If you only consider $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$, then why do you need a general $\Gamma$?

Comment: As per my knowledge, we can extend the result to $\ell_1(\Gamma)$ if we could prove it for $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$. However, knowing the SSD of the norm for $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ solves my query.

Comment: What do you mean by "the mapping"? and by "dual norm"?

Comment: Sir, here the $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ defines a dual norm on $\ell_1(\Gamma)$, which is a strictly convex dual norm, which will imply the predual norm on $c_0(\Gamma)$ is gateaux differentiable. And for a strictly convex Banach space $(X_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$, we can find a continuous, linear and one-one operator $T: (X_1, \Vert \cdot \Vert_1) \to (X_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$ such that $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert x \Vert_1+\Vert x \Vert_2, x \in X_1$ defines a strictly convex norm on $X_1$.

Comment: There is no mention of of $T$ after "such that" in your latter comment.

Comment: I haven't quite caught where the confusion arises. (The set NA$(X)$ depends of course on the norm on $X$ chosen.) And who are the authors of the book you are quoting?

Comment: Ok sir. My confusion is to check whether the result that $\ell_1$ with the new norm is SSD or not. Is there a posibility that, if we take the original norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ to be SSD, does this imply the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is SSD for $f \in NA(c_0(\mathbb{N})$.  Also, I have mentioned the author names in my recent edits.